# C# After inserting from DataGridView into MySQL data are truncated

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, winforms, datagridview

I have made a small application that automatically inserts data from datagridview into a MySQL table by clicking a button. My problem is that after pasting into MySQL table some data is simply truncated because it has more strings than the table allows. This happens without me noticing and I am looking for a solution. Simply increasing the number of strings in MySQL is not a solution.  At the end, only data records should be saved that have really not been shortened automatically. Thanks

here is my code:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0  ; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++) // dòng
        {
                    string str = "server=xxxx; database=xxxx; uid=xxxx; pwd=xxxxxx;";
                    MySqlConnection constr = new MySqlConnection(str);
                    constr.Open();
                    String cmdText = "INSERT  INTO table (spalte1, spalte2, spalte3) VALUES ('"
                                               + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "','"
                                               + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "','"
                                               + Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "','"
                                               + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "')";
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, constr);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            constr.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why is increasing the size of the column value(s) in MySQL not an option? And if you really cant increase the size of the column(s) then you should do some kind of character limitation on the front end and do a validation on the back end to prevent this.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for the answer. It is not an opimal option because I do not know tomorrow in the columns how many characters I will have. Then I have to set everything in MySQL to maximum so that I don't have a problem with unnoticed shortened data being saved. I imagined a SQL error message like "data is too long" or something like that

Comment: Since MySQL is truncating, I don't think it is going to produce an error, if you can set MySQL to not truncate, then maybe it will generate an error message, but as I stated previously, if you are going to put a limit on how much your columns can hold then you should be validating this on the backend and return an error before ever doing your Insert. Also alerting the user on the front end that you have a limit would be helpful to the user.

Answer (score 3):

You want to set the [SQL Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html) of MySQL to [Traditional](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_traditional). This will enable [Strict SQL Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict), which will raise an error when data is truncated during insert or update.

As others have commented, a user-friendly approach is to additionally make the users aware of the limit before they try to store data.

Comment: Thank you NineBerry. That seems to help. Does the STRICT mode then apply to all MYSQL tables or only to one table created with the mode?

Comment: It applies to all tables. You can switch on/off strict mode independently for transactional tables and non-transactional tables, but I don't see that as relevant